# Where did the idiom "scot-free" come from?

Tags: idioms, american-english

As in, that criminal got off scot-free despite a mountain of evidence that would seem to indicate his guilt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the etymonline.com entry for [scot](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=scot&searchmode=none):

> **scot-free**
>   O.E. *scotfreo* "exempt from royal tax," from *scot* "royal tax," from O.N. skot "contribution, reckoning, shot" + *freo* (see *free*). Related to O.E. *sceotan* "to pay, contribute," Du. *schot*, Ger. *Schoß* "tax, contribution" (see *shot*). O.Fr. *escot* (Fr. *écot*) "share" is a Germanic loan-word.

You see this remnant also in the phrase "[scot and lot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scot_and_lot)."